# Why use Android Plugin for Gradle 2.0.x versus 1.5.0?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

After a couple of hours of googling I have been unable to find a good overview reference describing why to move from plugin 1.5.1 to a 2.0.x version, or at least the pros and cons. I have found release notes for the 1.x.x versions ([http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html) and information about the new build system being developed (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). This new information is too detailed for me to decide if I should upgrade.

I know that 2.0.x is less stable than 1.5.1, so need to understand the gains I would get using it versus the risks of using a less mature plugin.

Can you explain or point me to a reference explaining the advantages of the 2.0.x plugin versus 1.5.0?

Comment: Right now? AFAIK, you use a 2.0.0 beta of the Android Plugin for Gradle if you are using the Android Studio 2.0 beta. Otherwise, I recommend that you stick with the 1.5.x series until Android Studio 2.0 goes final. Pretty much all the changes in 2.0.0 are tied into Instant Run, which AFAIK requires Android Studio 2.0 beta to actually be used.